# Understanding Java and Generic Arrays

Tags: java, arrays, generics, arraylist

I am trying to do the following code:

```
public class AddressManager
{
    private ArrayList<Address>[] array;
    private int depth;

    public AddressManager(int d, int s, Address a)
    {
        array = new ArrayList<Address>[d];
    }
}
```

There is more to my code, but this amount of code is sufficient to show my problem. Of course, netbeans shows a compile error to do with generic arrays, on the line with "new ArrayList...", and i have read up alot about this.

There are explainations all over the web stating things about the compiler not being able to verify types in assignments if you do this, and lots of questions about this are right here on StackOverflow! There are also supposedly ways to work around this, so long as you show the compiler that "You know what you're doing!". The issue is that i can't get this to work, i can't understand the explanations, and i really do want an array of arraylists.

Could someone please explain in more simple language what i can do to get around this error in my specific case? I have tried the following sort of idea:

```
private Object[] array;
array = (ArrayList<Address>[]) new Object[d];
```

But it seems it can not be cast correctly, even though one of the sites i saw said you could do something like this, or use "@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")" with something or other. Please, i need this in a way that is more clear than examples that don't quite match my situation like [This solution](http://www.coderanch.com/t/557852/java/java/Generic-Array-Creation-Error-Message), which works great for maps, but not ArrayLists.

The other answers to questions just like mine on StackOverflow may be very helpful indeed, but i do not understand them very well, or i would not be writing this request for something more down to earth.

Comment: The following might help: http://stackoverflow.com/a/20023599/1057429

Comment: @amdixon of course he can do it - only that it won't compile... :)

Comment: alfasin, to take a similar approach to your suggestion, i wouldnt mind an "ArrayList of ArrayLists".... eg ArrayList<ArrayList<Address>>.... however, lets say i add some items to the array with array.add.... will the FIRST thing i add to the array be in "array.get(0)", and the second thing i add be in "array.get(1)" ? It is very important that this order is maintained. Would this be an adequate solution that wouldn't throw errors in my face?

Comment: Yes that's the preferred approach. Of course that you can do [*this*](http://stackoverflow.com/a/530289/1057429) as well - only that it's not recommended.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is nothing wrong with the following:

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
ArrayList<Address>[] array = (ArrayList<Address>[]) new ArrayList<?>[d];
```

You just need to be sure that you really are only storing `ArrayList<Address>` in the array. If you are sure of that, then you can safely suppress the warning. There's nothing wrong with using generic arrays in principle. The compiler is just protecting you from doing something like this accidentally.

Comment: This appears to work for me without the use of the supress warnings code! :o

Comment: Okay i'm not sure why the compiler would protect you against that, since there are so many things that can go wrong in any program... but I really like this answer. I honestly did think it wasn't allowed at all, which seems a little too restrictive on such a powerful idea. The way to cast it is a little odd but i think i see why it allows it this way. Thank you.