# How to create generics array

Tags: java, arrays, generics

I have 2 interfaces `Sub` and `Obs` as illustrated below:

```
public interface Sub<O extends Obs<? extends Sub>>{
   public void addObs(O);

   public void removeObs(O);
}

public interface Obs<S entends Sub<?>>{
   public void update(S);
}
```

Now there are 2 concrete implementations of the above as class `Vie` which implements `Obs` and class `Mod` which implements `Sub` as below:

```
public class Vie<M extends Mod> implements Obs<M>{
   public void update(M){
      //some code;
   }
} 

public class Mod implements Sub<Vie<Mod>>{

   Vie<Mod>[] obs = new Vie<Mod>[0]; //This is the line of error.

   public void addObs(Vie<Mod>){
     //some code;
   }

   public void removeObs(Vie<Mod>){
      //some code;
   }
}
```

Now my problem is when I want to initialise the array of `Vie` in the class `Mod` I get an error *"cannot create generics array of `Vie<Mod>`"*. So how can I initialise an array of `Vie<Mod>` containing 0 elements.

**NOTE** I know of a solution:

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
Vie<Mod>[] obs = (Vie<Mod>[]) new Vie<?>[0];
```

I am not looking for this can anybody suggest anything else?

**Edit** I have already posted the answer that was there in the question which is attached as duplicate to this question. I was not looking for answers like that. I can share this another [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20027460/4726707) like mine. But my point is that **is there any other way?**.

Now I add a second part to my question:

If no other solution, following my suggested solution, are there any problems in this casting as it would not be checked at the compile time. Is there any scope or any runtime exceptions?

Comment: Use a `List` instead of raw arrays.

Comment: The solution you showed in the question is the only way. (Or use a List like @Jarrod says.)

Comment: @Blip Your question boils down to "the compiler is telling me I can't do this, I know there is a workaround but I don't like it and I want to do what the compiler says I can't do".

Comment: @Radiodef are there any problems in this casting as it would not be checked at the compile time. Is there any scope or any runtime exceptions?

Comment: @Blip it also surprised me. your question looks fine (it already has an answer, but that doesn't reflect negatively on your question) +1

Comment: for future reference [asking anonymous down  voters for an explanation is not constructive](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252826/is-asking-reasons-for-downvote-in-comments-non-constructive), there is a perfectly good reason for the down vote if you hover over the down vote arrow. *This question does not show any research effort; it is unclear or not useful*. Duplicates fall afoul of 2 out of 3 of these explanations. No research effort **and** not useful. *"How can I improve my question?"* is a different type of comment.

Comment: No, casting the array won't cause a problem. The creation is not allowed because the unchecked `Vie<Mod>[]` doesn't behave as an array. Arrays throw an exception if you put wrong elements in them, and `Vie<Mod>[]` will not throw an exception if someone converts it back to `Vie[]` or `Vie<?>[]` and puts e.g. a `Vie<Integer>` in it.